# How do I split a list of string into records?

Tags: r, split

I `readLines` from a file with records

```
record:1
...
end

junk

record:2
...
end

more junk
```

So the positions of records are

```
beg.pos <- grep("^record:[0-9]*",l)
end.pos <- grep("^end",l)
```

So, how do I `split` the vector `l` into a list of vectors of strings:

```
list(c("record:1",...,"end"),
     c("record:2",...,"end"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mapply(function(b, e) c(l[b:e]), beg.pos, end.pos, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "record:1" "..."      "end"     
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "record:2" "..."      "end"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
# Your data:
l = c("record:1", "...", "end", "", "junk", "", "record:2", "...", "end", "", "more junk")    
beg.pos <- grep("^record:[0-9]*",l)
end.pos <- grep("^end",l)

# Splitting:
l2 = list()
for (i in 1:length(beg.pos)) {
  l2 = c(l2, list(l[beg.pos[i]:end.pos[i]]))
}
```

Output:

```
> l2
[[1]]
[1] "record:1" "..."      "end"     
[[2]]
[1] "record:2" "..."      "end"
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really test this on your data, but something like this ought to work:

```
beg.pos <- grep("^record:[0-9]*",l)
end.pos <- grep("^end",l)

listing <- list()

# Create a listing of sequences
for(i in 1:length(beg.pos)) { 
   listing[[i]] <- beg.pos[i]:end.pos[i]
}

# Return a list of subsets
lapply(listing, function(x) l[x])
```